# WinForms - Embedding CNN Live Video URL

Tags: c#, html, winforms, video, popup

I have a C# WinForms application and a client has requested to have a streaming CNN video player integrated in to it. CNN uses a flash player located at http://www.cnn.com/video/live/live.html?stream=stream1

However if I embed a WebBrowser object and point it at the URL, the web site wants to fire a popup outside of my WebBrowser control. If I disable it (using the NewWindow event handlers), it throws up a javascript alert message. If I allow it, it opens a new IE instance outside of my application withe CNN video in it.

The only thought I had was to recreate the HTML and override the javascript settings for their flash object (http://z.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.element/apps/CNNLive/2.1.6.2/assets/scripts/liveplayersettings.js) in order to turn off the popup flags.

Anyone have thoughts on a way to accomplish showing the site while doing so inside of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up hacking the Javascript that CNN uses, dunno how long it'll last but this was the quickest way to accomplish what I wanted without all the added overhead of the other solutions.

```
    protected void webBrowser_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && DefaultPage == BrowserPage.CNN)
        {
            HtmlElement head = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptElement = webBrowser.Document.CreateElement("script");
            IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptElement.DomElement;
            string popupBlocker = "if(typeof settings != 'undefined') { settings.FORCE_POPUP = false; }";
            element.text = popupBlocker;
            head.AppendChild(scriptElement);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows media player will play a flash file if you have the latest ffdshow installed. You could pass it the url and let an embed windows media player play it.

VLC will do it too, whichever you prefer. The api for Windows media player is probably a little easier though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest download and using the Microsoft Expression Encoder SDK. It can capture live feeds from other websites: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602440(v=expression.40).aspx

You can scroll down to the section "Working with Live Broadcasting projects" and it explains how to capture live video feeds from the web.

If the Expression SDK will not work for you, then I can only suggest that you will have to reverse engineer their Javascript and write some kind of HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse type application to get the data and stream it yourself in your program.